# How do you access the Keyblade Graveyard?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

I'm at the end game where Xemnas is all who is left of Organisation XIII and Riku is back to normal. I read that in Final Mix there's a place called the Keyblade Graveyard which I can enter from a portal in the Hall of the Conerstone.

Problem is there's nothing there as I went back to Disney Castle to get remaining Puzzle Pieces there and in the Timeless River. I also read that Chip and Dale were supposed to have summoned me but nothing.

I have completed all tournaments with the exception to this Goddess cup (which I have seen a trophy for on the PS3) and I have completed every episode. So I am wondering, how do I access the Keyblade Graveyard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to beat the game first. Then when you load that save you will get a few messages about new episodes. Then you can proceed to the Hall of the Cornerstone and the portal will be there.